# htaccess redirection and rewrite from php to html

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am stuck with .htaccess modification, need a little help.
First off, here is whats inside my htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

For example, I created the file named test.php and uploaded to my server.

I want my server to behave like this.

```
http://example.com/test/test.html -> http://example.com/test/test.html(as it is)
http://example.com/test/test.php -> http://example.com/test/test.html
```

but with the .htaccess I have right now,
I still have both .php and .html which may be considered as file duplication by search engine crawler like Google robot (isn't it?).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this .htaccess code

```
# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on

#Create friendly URL
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)\.html$ test/$1\.php [L]
```

**OR**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.html [L]
```

**OR**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## .php to .html
# To externally redirect /test/test.php to /test/test.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.html [R,L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks Sumit for quick reply. 
But my file name can be anything. like index.php, company.php, mission.php, access.php, etc... so better to use regex right?

Comment: if that not work check my `OR` portion of answer, that will defiantly work

Comment: @norixxx you have `test` folder so rule may be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^test/(.*)\.php$
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) /test/$1.html [L]`

Comment: still not workin' /test/index.php -> O.K. but if i type /test/index.html -> "The requested URL /test/index.html was not found on this server." my server says. my htaccess now: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^test/(.*)\.php$
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) /test/$1.html [L]

Answer (score 1):

This is a configuration file of apache '.htaccess' if you still want to configure then change

RewriteEngine on

I hope this work

Comment: Thanks. I wrote 'RewriteEngine on' at first row in my htaccess. still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this in one .htaccess file in root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html             [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.php  /$1/$2.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

For silent mapping, replace [R=301,NC,L] with [NC,L]